# How to iterate through all possible combinations in an simple array

Tags: php

Kindly help me with my code:

```
$a[1]='cloropil';
$a[2]='rodopayta';
$r=2;
$c=1;
$f= while($c<=$r){ echo $a[$c];;
$e = $c++ };
while($c<=$r){
echo $f;
$r++;
}
while($c<=$r){
echo $e;
$r++;
}
```

I want its output to be like this:

```
$a[1]='cloropil';
$a[2]='rodopayta';
$r=2;
$c=1;
while($c<=$r){
 echo $a[$c];
   while($c<=$r){
    echo $a[$c];
    $c++;
   }
 $c++;
}
```

How ever the out put is blank.
it should even display at least "cloropil".
Is this even possible?
I want to display something like this:

cloropilcloropil
cloropilrodopyta
rodopytacloropil
rodopytarodopyta

thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please provide one version of your code that you need help with, it doesn't make sense to have two blocks of code. Please also try to clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This code is too much of a mess to try to disambiguate. If you could show an example of the output you are requiring I can try to help more. Unfortunately the code above is not structured properly and the example you are showing is more code not the actual output of the code.

Comment: apologies in my coding I've been trying to explore php about a month till now. what I am trying display:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be what you are looking for?:

```
<?php
$a[]='cloropil';
$a[]='rodopayta';

    // You first iterate over each
    for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) 
        {
            // As you iterate through the first round, you iterate
            // again to match pairs but include the first iteration
            // value with this second 
            foreach($a as $val) 
                echo $a[$i].'=>'.$val.'<br />';
        }
?>
```

**Gives you:**

```
cloropil=>cloropil
cloropil=>rodopayta
rodopayta=>cloropil
rodopayta=>rodopayta
```

Comment: Thank you very much I love you so much! hehehe